# Unknown visit in Google Analytics from Facebook after post with Graph API

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-graph

I'm using Graph API to sent post to my Facebook page. After a few minutes later, in google analytics I'm seeing visits from 2-3 countries from different places of the world. And they all go a 404 page.

I have inspected the specific link, its like this:

```
www.example.com/lUPTN/VQhdZ/VRchZ/?fbclid=IwAR3HKZ5cwcd-zCiY6SaHQ_LkWsf98Jgvoxtak49lZ26N_X1Qbiq1chSVCsw
```

The post that I sent is ok. I see it on my page. And links work properly. But I don't know what this link is. Has anyone see this before?

Comment: Are you sure that those events are related?   If you submit a different post to Facebook do you then see other similar hits?

Comment: I think it is related because
1. The hits come with fbclid param
2. It started with my graph api post
3. Same countries also hit the page that i share
4. When i post manually on the page, hits are not coming

I dont think that the hits are organic. @StephenOstermiller